# Two linear maps, domain and codomain of both connected via a bijective linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L_A : \Bbb{R^n}\to\Bbb{R^m}$, which has a matrix $A$. Let $L:V\to W$. Let $E$ be a basis of $V$ and $F$ a basis of $W$. Moreover we have bijective linear maps $P_E : V\to \Bbb{R^n}$ and $P_F : W\to \Bbb{R^m}$.

How can I show that $P_E(Ker (L))=Null(A)$? I was told to draw a diagram, which is a sort of four directional map, but I cant make any sense of it. The point is, these are both subspaces of $\Bbb{R^n}$ so we can prove they are equal by inclusion, or by showing they have the same basis. I don't think there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key piece of information the diagram provides is the commuting relationship $$L_A \circ P_E=P_F \circ L$$
First if $x\in P_E\Big(\ker(L)\Big) $ then $x=P_E (v)$ for some $v\in \ker(L)$ and $$Ax=L_A(x)=(L_A \circ P_E)(v)=(P_F\circ L)(v)=P_F(0)=0$$ This shows $x\in N(A)$. On the other hand, if $x\in N(A),$ and we take $v=P_E^{-1}(x)$ then $$L(v)=(L\circ P_E^{-1})(x)=(P_F^{-1}\circ L_A)(x)=P_F^{-1}\big(Ax\big)=P_F^{-1}(0)=0$$ This shows $v\in \ker(L)$ meaning $x=P_E(v)\in P_E\Big(\ker(L)\Big)$ and we have our result.